# How to clone and pull all repositories from an Organization?

Tags: linux, github, clone, pull, organization

I saw some implementations using github's API to retrieve the list of libraries, but in my case didn't catch all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is interested, I wrote a small bash file to do this, hope it helps.

Replace *XXXXXXXX* with the name of your target organization

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 << END

import re
import urllib.request


ORGANIZATION = "XXXXXXXX"
URL_BASE = "https://github.com/{}?page=".format(ORGANIZATION)
URL_CLONE = "https://github.com/{}/{}.git"


page = 1
libraries = True
urls = []
while libraries:
    url = URL_BASE + str(page)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    code = ''
    if resp.code == 200:
        resp_bytes = resp.read()
        code = resp_bytes.decode("utf8")
        resp.close()
    libraries = re.findall('href="/{}/([^"]+)[^>]+codeRepository'.format(ORGANIZATION), code)
    for library in libraries:
        url = URL_CLONE.format(ORGANIZATION, library)
        urls.append(url)
    page += 1


with open('libraries.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as ofile:
    ofile.write('\n'.join(urls))

END

while read i; do
  git clone $i || echo "    Error while cloning, probably already exists"
done <libraries.txt

ls -d */ | xargs -I{} git -C {} pull
```